# How do I let jenkins and m2eclipse share the same maven repository

Tags: eclipse, maven, ssh, jenkins

How do I configure m2eclipse ( maven plugin for eclipse ) to use a centralized maven repository that is also used in jenkins.

The default user settings in m2eclipse is something like "home/user/.m2"
How can we do something like "ssh user@192.168.1.200:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2"?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on _why_ you want to do this? There might be a completely different answer then.

Comment: Hi, we are using jenkins in our workplace shared by programmers. We have a lot of separate eclipse projects, and each of this project is manage in jenkins maven build system which includes versioning. So, my minimum requirement is that the project that I am working on should be able to download the dependency with the correct version specified in the pom.xml, so it would have to access our maven repository used in jenkins. Has anyone had not set-up something like this? Or how do workplaces use jenkins and m2eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

A neat and easy way to do it is to use a repository manager. Sonatype's [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/) seems to be the most popular, but there are others (e.g. JFrog Artifactory and Apache Archiva). They run as HTTP servers, and you can change your Maven configuration (both locally and for Jenkins) to [use it as a mirror](http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/maven-sect-single-group.html) for any Maven repository (e.g. the Central Maven repo), or use it to host your own repositories.

Comment: Just an observation: most popular != best.

Comment: I do, but the equation I mentioned has nothing to do with specific products and it is true nevertheless :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to do that. Your POM files list dependencies and they list repositories. Maven will then resolve your dependencies against all known repositories (the listed ones and the "build-in" ones, like Maven central).

Maven will do this in m2eclipse, when running a Maven build. Maven will also do that when running the build on Jenkins. So if both machines can connect to all the repositories listed in your POM files, both will retrieve the same artifacts and both will do the same builds.

You should really not try to share the local copy of the artifacts. That is as bad as if I and you try to share our Maven artifacts using a network share. Maven is designed to find and manage those artifacts and you are trying to do *its* job with this question.

Comment: You mean, maven can reference projects in my workspace without having them configured in project build path(.classpath)?, So then, I still have to checkout all the project dependency in our own internal repositories then. I was thinking of just letting maven download the jar files for the dependency project which is built in our jenkins, without having to deal with raw project source codes and which projects I still have to checkout into my workspace, so my main project could be build.

Comment: And also, how do you add an independent jar file that has is not found in a maven repository? Would everyone has to do a maven install with that jar file?

Comment: You are on the right track: Either you checkout all your internal projects together, so Maven can build them together (using a multi module POM). Or you build one project, publish it to a Maven repository of your choice (which might be company internal, as in the other answer) and have the other builds fetch the jar from there again. For "jar only" libraries, you can add them to a repository giving them a dummy id: http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html