# Ant to maven conversion

Tags: maven

I need to convert few projects from ant to maven. I know the basics of both, also read a lot of articles on how to. However, is it a good idea to write a pom using eclipse? Or is it better to write it without using eclipse? The M2Eclipse plugin needs maven to be tweaked more, will the changes related to M2Eclipse cause problems when the war is built on jenkins?

Comment: Why does it matter what you write the pom in? Other than that IDEs probably give you some amount of completion and possibly artifact lookup.

Comment: The hardest thing is to match your dependencies to Maven coordinates. If you don't know them, the checksum can help.

Comment: @JF Meier What do you mean by checksum? Thanks.

Comment: You can compute the sha1 value of the jars, then search for it in Nexus/Artifactory/MavenCentral.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally have done migration from Ant to Maven2. IMO it is better to write pom.xml on your own so that you wont face any last minute surprises as well as you will get complete overall knowledge on what you are exactly doing with your pom file.

However if you still want to go with m2e, from my experience it did not create any problems at all. Regarding the build - I guess there shouldn't be any issue. You can refer this link if you need more info about m2e and jekins - [m2e and jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12117934/how-do-i-let-jenkins-and-m2eclipse-share-the-same-maven-repository?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Answer (score 1):

**Pros of using Eclipse IDE:**

- The **formatting of pom.xml** will be taken care, when you add the '*maven-eclipse-codestyle.xml*' to the code formatter, as mentioned [here](https://maven.apache.org/developers/conventions/code.html). Formatting will be harder when you do it without an IDE.
- The **auto-completion feature** of eclipse will make your coding easier, since it will automatically sense the open tags and close them. You need to close all the open tags manually, if you don`t use an IDE.
- You can view the **dependency hierarchy** of the dependencies added and hence it might be a bit helpful while managing the dependencies.This can be extremely useful ,when you have transitive dependencies (Dependencies within other dependencies). You can find more about transitive dependencies [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies).
- An IDE will **warn you of common mistakes** that may occur while coding (something like, 'forgetting to close an open tag','placing a tag in an incorrect location'). This will save a whole lot of time. If you don`t use an IDE, you need to correct the mistakes only when you get an exception after executing a maven command.
- Eclipse will **warn of missing artifacts** (when the dependencies are not present in the local repository), which can help you to fix it before executing the maven goal.

**Cons of using Eclipse IDE:**

- m2e plugin will throw '*Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration*' **errors all over your pom.xml files**. These errors won`t affect your build, but may be quite annoying.